# Tabs dentro de um modal ao clicar desaparece o modal

Tags: html, html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap

Estou implementando um modal e dentro dele estou colocando `tabs`. 
Porém quando eu clico em alguma aba da tab o modal desaparece. 
Vejam as imagens. 
Uso o bootstrap.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que a url muda..

como resolver ??

meu html

Saúde

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3>Pacientes</h3>
                    <br></br>
                    <button id="btnSalvar" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdicionarPaciente" class="btn btn-default ">Adicionar novo paciente</button>
                    <button id="btnImprimir" type="button"  class="btn btn-default pull-right ">Imprimir</button>               
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Foto</th>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                    <th>Idade</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody ng-repeat="pac in pacientes ">
                                <tr>                            
                                    <td>{{}}</td>
                                    <td>{{}}</td>
                                    <td>{{}}</td>
                                    <td>                                
                                         <div  class="btn-group">
                                            <button id="opcoes" type="button" class="btn btn-danger vermDigifred btn-xs dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="dropdown"> </button>                                                                                   
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                <li><a  id="btnExcluirRegistro" ng-click="excluirPacientes(pac)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Excluir registro</a></li>
                                                <li> <a id="btnAlterarRegistro" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAlterarDistrito" ng-click="alterarPacientes(pac)" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Alterar registro</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>      
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modalAdicionarPaciente" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div style="color: white; background-color: #0c4677" class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">
                        <strong>Adicionar Paciente</strong>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form novalidate name="frmPaciente" id="formCadastro" role="form">
                        <div class="row">                       
                         <div >
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6" >
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                      <input type="file" id="file"   fileinput="file" filepreview="filepreview"  />

                                      </div>
                                </div>
                                   <div class=" form-group col-md-6">
                                      <img id="imagemPromocao" src=""   ng-src="{{filepreview}}" class="img-responsive img-circle" ng-show="filepreview" ng-model="promocao.foto"   />  
                                   </div>
                                </div>


                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label>Nome *:</label> <input maxlength="70" required="required" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="distrito.nome" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label>CNS *:</label> <input maxlength="70" required="required" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="distrito.nome" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label>Nome Social *:</label> <input maxlength="70" required="required" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="distrito.nome" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label>Sexo:</label> <select ng-model="distrito.municipio.idMunicipio" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="{{dis.entidade.municipio.idMunicipio}}" ng-repeat="dis in distritos">{{dis.entidade.municipio.nome}}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label>Data Nascimento:</label> <input maxlength="70" required="required" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="distrito.nome" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label>Idade:</label> <input maxlength="70" required="required" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="distrito.nome" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <div class="tabbable"> 
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">                    
                                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dados">Dados</a></li>
                                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#documentos">Documentos</a></li>
                                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#pacientes">Pacientes</a></li>
                                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#caracteristicas">Características</a></li>
                                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#personalizados">Personalizados</a></li>
                                </ul>

                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div id="dados" class="tab-pane fade in active">                        
                                        <p>Some content.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="documentos" class="tab-pane fade">
                                        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="pacientes" class="tab-pane fade">
                                        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="caracteristicas" class="tab-pane fade">
                                        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="personalizados" class="tab-pane fade">
                                        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button style="background-color: #b51e27; color: white;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="salvarPacientes()">Salvar</button>
                    <button style="background-color: #b51e27; color: white;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="salvarPacientes()">Salvar e novo</button>
                    <button style="background-color: #b51e27; color: white;" type="button" class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="cancelarAlteracaoPacientes(pac)" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja como está a importação do `css` e do seu `js` no `header do html`
veja a sequencia.

1. `CSS do Bootstrap`
2. `CSS customizado`
3. `JQuery`
4. `JS do Bootstrap`
5. `JS customizado`

Sendo que os arquivos `.JS` podem ficar no final do documento antes do fechamento da tag `</body>`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Pacientes</h3>
        <br></br>
        <button id="btnSalvar" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdicionarPaciente" class="btn btn-default ">Adicionar novo paciente</button>
        <button id="btnImprimir" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right ">Imprimir</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Foto</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Idade</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="pac in pacientes ">
              <tr>
                <td>{{}}</td>
                <td>{{}}</td>
                <td>{{}}</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <button id="opcoes" type="button" class="btn btn-danger vermDigifred btn-xs dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="dropdown"> </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a id="btnExcluirRegistro" ng-click="excluirPacientes(pac)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Excluir registro</a></li>
                      <li> <a id="btnAlterarRegistro" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAlterarDistrito" ng-click="alterarPacientes(pac)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Alterar registro</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalAdicionarPaciente" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div style="color: white; background-color: #0c4677" class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">
          <strong>Adicionar Paciente</strong>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form novalidate name="frmPaciente" id="formCadastro" role="form">
          <div class="row">
            <div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="file" id="file" fileinput="file" filepreview="filepreview" />

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class=" form-group col-md-6">
                <img id="imagemPromocao" src="" ng-src="{{filepreview}}" class="img-responsive img-circle" ng-show="filepreview" ng-model="promocao.foto" />
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>Nome *:</label> <input maxlength="70" required="required" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="distrito.nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label>CNS *:</label> <input maxlength="70" required="required" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="distrito.nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>Nome Social *:</label> <input maxlength="70" required="required" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="distrito.nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label>Sexo:</label> <select ng-model="distrito.municipio.idMunicipio" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="{{dis.entidade.municipio.idMunicipio}}" ng-repeat="dis in distritos">{{dis.entidade.municipio.nome}}</option>
                                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label>Data Nascimento:</label> <input maxlength="70" required="required" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="distrito.nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label>Idade:</label> <input maxlength="70" required="required" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="distrito.nome" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dados">Dados</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#documentos">Documentos</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#pacientes">Pacientes</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#caracteristicas">Características</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#personalizados">Personalizados</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div id="dados" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <p>Some content.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="documentos" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="pacientes" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="caracteristicas" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="personalizados" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button style="background-color: #b51e27; color: white;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="salvarPacientes()">Salvar</button>
        <button style="background-color: #b51e27; color: white;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="salvarPacientes()">Salvar e novo</button>
        <button style="background-color: #b51e27; color: white;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancelarAlteracaoPacientes(pac)" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



</div>
```